# How to initialise state without useEffect running twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, In this toy problem the population of either the province selected or capital selected is displayed in the console. I'm trying to initialize the provinces state with a specific value but the value gets overwritten because useEffect runs twice on render where the first time is the correct population output but the second time is an empty array, how do I change my code to prevent this from happening?

```
import React, { Fragment,useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useDropdown from "./useDropdown";

const canada_json=[
    {
        "name" : "Alberta",
        "short" : "AB",
        "population" : 4067175,
        "capital" :"Edmonton",
        "capital_population" : 981280
        
    }
    ,
    {
        "name" : "British Columbia",
        "short" : "BC",        
        "population" : 4648055,
        "capital" : "Victoria",        
        "capital_population" : 92141 
    }] 

const Provincelist = () => {    
const [provinces, setprovinces] =useState([{value:{label: '', value : ""}}])

//Dropdown State I'm trying to initialise -  Defined as useDropdown(label, defaultState, options) 
const [province, ProvincesDropdown] = useDropdown("Provinces", "AB", provinces);

const [capitals, setcapitals] =useState([{value:{label: '', value : ""}}])    
const [capital, CapitalsDropdown, setcapital] = useDropdown("Capitals","", capitals);

//Populates Province Dropdown
useEffect(() =>{  
    const options = canada_json.map(d => ({
        "value" : d.short,
        "label" : d.name
      }))
      setprovinces(options)        
  },[]);

  //Populates Capital Dropdown after province selected and displays province population
  useEffect(() =>{ 
       
    const newlist = canada_json.filter(obj => obj.short === province) 
    const options = newlist.map(d => ({
        "value" : d.short,
        "label" : d.capital
      }))
      setcapitals(options) 
      
      const newlist2 = canada_json.filter(obj => obj.short === province).map((obj) => obj.population)     
      console.log(newlist2) 
  },[province]);
  
  //If Capital Dropdown changes display capital population
  useEffect(() =>{      
    const newlist = canada_json.filter(obj => obj.short === capital).map((obj) => obj.capital_population) 
    console.log(newlist)             
  },[capital]);      

  return (
    <Fragment>
    <ProvincesDropdown /> 
    <CapitalsDropdown />    
    </Fragment>
  )      
}
export default Provincelist;
```

This is the code for useDropDown

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useDropdown = (label, defaultState, options) => {
  const [state, updateState] = useState(defaultState);
  const id = `use-dropdown-${label.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()}`;
  const Dropdown = () => (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {label}
      <select
        id={id}
        value={state}
        onChange={e => updateState(e.target.value)}        
        disabled={!options.length}
      >
        
        <option hidden>Please Select...</option>
        {options.map(item => (
          <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
            {item.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  );
  return [state, Dropdown, updateState];
};

export default useDropdown;
```

Comment: The argument to useState() is the initialState. Why not set that to `canada_json.map(d => ({
        "value" : d.short,
        "label" : d.name
      }))` instead of an extra useEffect hook?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I replaced the first useEffect like you suggested but I'm still getting the same output. The problem I can see is with the third useEffect (capital dropdown) that runs last.

Answer (score 0):

if provinces will never update, save it inside `useRef`

population need to update so let's save it inside `useState`

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const canada_json = [
  {
    name: "Alberta",
    short: "AB",
    population: 4067175,
    capital: "Edmonton",
    capital_population: 981280
  },
  {
    name: "British Columbia",
    short: "BC",
    population: 4648055,
    capital: "Victoria",
    capital_population: 92141
  }
];

const Provincelist = () => {
  const provinces = useRef(
    canada_json.map((d) => ({
      value: d.short,
      label: d.name
    }))
  );

  const [population, setpopulation] = useState("");

  //Dropdown State I'm trying to initialise -  Defined as useDropdown(label, defaultState, options)
  const [province, ProvincesDropdown] = useDropdown(
    "Provinces",
    "AB",
    provinces.current
  );

  const [capitals, setcapitals] = useState([
    { value: { label: "", value: "" } }
  ]);

  const [capital, CapitalsDropdown] = useDropdown("Capitals", "", capitals);

  //Populates Capital Dropdown after province selected and displays province population
  useEffect(() => {
    const newlist = canada_json.filter((obj) => obj.short === province);
    const options = newlist.map((d) => ({
      value: d.short,
      label: d.capital
    }));
    setcapitals(options);
  }, [province]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (capital) {
      const newPopulation = canada_json.find(
        (province) => province.short === capital
      ).capital_population;
      setpopulation(newPopulation);
    }
  }, [capital]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ProvincesDropdown />
      <CapitalsDropdown />
      <span>{population}</span>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Provincelist;
```

Comment: Thanks, unrelated question but is it possible to use an async function with useRef? i.e. get the provinces values from a database and then save it inside a useRef.

Comment: i suggest you to consider a loading for your selects and move api call to useEffect(() => , []). whenever api call finished you should update the ref value and loading. with loading, you can somehow show users the field is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your `.map` in both of the `useEffect`s, the object that it returns does not match the shape of your initial value in both `useState`s for `provinces` and `capitals`

```
const [provinces, setprovinces] = useState([{value: {label: '', value: ''}}]);
useEffect(() =>{  
    const options = canada_json.map(d => ({
        "value" : d.short,
        "label" : d.name
      }))
    setprovinces(options);    
},[]);
```

should be changed to:

```
const [provinces, setprovinces] = useState([{value: {label: '', value: ''}}]);
useEffect(() =>{  
    const options = canada_json.map(d => ({
       value: {
         "value" : d.short,
         "label" : d.name
       }
    }))
    setprovinces(options);
},[]);
```